# 2nd level attribute drop down box not working

Tags: attributes, configurable-product

I have a configurable product with 2 attributes - colour and size. The first drop down box works and you can select your colour but nothing changes with the second drop down box even after you have a colour selected.
The 2 drop downs work in the quick view and it doesn't matter if I swap them over on the product page - if colour is top it works, if size it top it works but the bottom box doesn't.
The product page is http://www.machinetoolsandspares.co.uk/mens/em-mens-pyjamas.html
All the simple products are enabled, in stock, on the correct website. I have been through all the obvious stuff but I can't get this to work!
Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have some javascript code that transforms the dropdowns to nice-looking divs for the configurable products.
The problem is that, by default, when selecting something from the first dropdown, the second dropdown is enabled and repopulated with the proper values.
but your script does not get called after the second dropdown is repopulated and enabled.
That's why you still see it as disabled.

Run this in the browser console of the page you linked `$('attribute265').show();` and you should see the second dropdown near the dive that impersonates the dropdown.
Then change the value of the first dropdown.
You will see the dropdown enabled and filled with options.

You either give up the nice-looking divs, or you call the script that does the transformation after the first dropdown is changed.